# How do I calculate the remaining days from the latest login and the session expiration date of 180 days in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to display the N of days left from the latest user login and the date of session expiration, that lasts 6 months.
I have a TextView with a countdown "N of days left".
Assuming the the last login was performed today, how can I get dynamically a countdown?

Comment: If you are using server api for login then better use token expiration from server side.

Comment: the api won't have a token expiration but only date of login.

Comment: create 2 date objects, get number of milliseconds in each date, get the difference in milliseconds, convert the result into days (divide it by the number of miliseconds in a day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Constant for easy modifying
val EXPIRATION_DAYS = 180

// Get current date
val calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance()
calendar.time = Date()
val currentDate = cal.time

// Adding to current date needed amount of days
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, EXPIRATION_DAYS)

// Get modified date
val after180DaysDate = cal.time

// Calculating difference between dates    
val difference = after180DaysDate.time - currentDate.time

// Converting milliseconds to days
val convertedDifference = (difference / (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000))

Log.e("TAG", "$convertedDifference of days left")
```

Hope, this helps.